# How do I make a curved surface out of rectangular blocks?

Tags: collision-detection, box2d, geometry, curves

For a *Peggle*-like game, I want to make blocks that follow a curve, like this:

[image: blocks along a curve]

The blocks would then disappear as the ball hits them.

I managed to draw some horizontally, but I'm having trouble making them follow a path:

[image: my attempt at path-following blocks]

How do I do this? Do I need to create *Box2D* objects with custom vertices?

Comment: Do you want the boxes to simply not overlap or do you want there to be no gaps anywhere? (I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "offsetting the object Y axis according to the object angle").

Comment: You can't fill a curve with non-overlapping *rectangles*, so you're going to *have to* create some custom geomety if you want no gaps.

Comment: @RoyT. The gaps aren't important. My real problem is to compute the position of the block which follow each other with different angle.

Comment: The way I would approach this is to define a series of vertices that act as the common corners between each box. Even using a path to define them, you still need additional parameters to define the distance between the vertices and how long each box is.

Comment: @Anko Yes, it's a solution but it'll be more difficult to create object with custom vertices.

Comment: @Thebluefish It's a good idea. I thought at a same thing with the help of Pythagore Theorem. If you have the box width, the angle and the length between two vertices, you can find the last side wich would be the Y offset for the top-right box coordinate if we refer as the last pictures. But i have no idea how to implement it.

Comment: The "boxes" on the first image are not boxes, they are pairs of triangles: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Tzuql.png

Answer (score 14):

Given a "root" curve, here's how you might generate block vertices.

[image: Bézier with blocks]

The root curve is in the middle, in black. Its control points are shown with red `X`s.

*In short*: I made a [Bézier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bezier_curve) and sampled it (at a configurable rate). I then found the [perpendicular vector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) of the vector from each sample to the next, [normalised](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector) it, and [scaled](http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/vectors.html) it to to a (configurable) half-width, first to the left, then inversely to the right. Then drew it.

Stuff you could add to this:

- **Change parameters**, for wider or thicker blocks.
- **Generate triangles** (as [egarcia mentions](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/70669/how-do-i-make-a-curve-made-of-rectangular-blocks#comment127526_70669)) and texture them. It would look much like [that first picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hzT0.jpg)!
- [**Sample the curve at equal arc lengths**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11980166/equally-distribute-objects-across-a-bezier-curve) ([here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/6009/arc-length-of-bezier-curves) too), to size blocks' widths consistently. (In this implementation, the central control point's position affects blocks' relative sizes.)

---

Here's my code. It's written in [Lua](http://www.lua.org/) (for the [LÖVE](https://love2d.org/) game framework), but I think it's readable for anyone.

```lua
local v = require "vector"

-- A function that makes bezier functions
-- Beziers have start point     p0
--              control point   p1
--              end point       p2
local function makeBezierFunction(p0,p1,p2)
    return function (t)
        local pow = math.pow
        return pow( (1-t),2 ) * p0
               + 2 * (1-t) * t * p1
               + pow(t,2) * p2
    end
end

love.graphics.setBackgroundColor(255, 255, 255)
function love.draw()
    local line = love.graphics.line
    local colour = love.graphics.setColor

    -- Bezier sampling parameters
    local nSegments = 10
    local segIncr = 1/nSegments

    -- Bezier definition: Start (`p0`), control (`p1`) and end `p2`) point
    local p0 = v(100,100)
    local p1 = v( love.mouse.getX(), love.mouse.getY() )
    local p2 = v(500,100)
    local controlPoints = {p0,p1,p2}
    local bez = makeBezierFunction(p0,p1,p2)

    -- Sample the bezier
    for i=0,1-segIncr,segIncr do
        colour(0, 0, 0)
        local x1,y1 = bez(i        ):unpack()
        local x2,y2 = bez(i+segIncr):unpack()
        line(x1,y1,x2,y2)

        -- Find left and right points.
        local center = v(x1, y1)
        local forward = v(x2, y2) - center
        local left = center + forward:perpendicular():normalize_inplace() * 10
        local right = center - forward:perpendicular():normalize_inplace() * 10

        -- Draw a line between them.
        line(left.x, left.y, right.x, right.y)

        -- Find *next* left and right points, if we're not beyond the end of
        -- the curve.
        if i + segIncr <= 1 then
            local x3, y3 = bez(i+segIncr*2):unpack()
            local center2 = v(x2, y2)
            local forward2 = v(x3, y3) - center2
            local left2 = center2 + forward2:perpendicular():normalize_inplace() * 10
            local right2 = center2 - forward2:perpendicular():normalize_inplace() * 10

            -- Connect the left and right of the current to the next point,
            -- forming the top and bottom surface of the blocks.
            colour(0, 0xff, 0)
            line(left.x, left.y, left2.x, left2.y)
            colour(0, 0, 0xff)
            line(right.x, right.y, right2.x, right2.y)
        end
    end

    -- Draw an X at the control points
    for _,p in ipairs(controlPoints) do
        local x,y = p:unpack()
        colour(0xff,0x00,0x00)
        line(x-5,y-5, x+5,y+5)
        line(x-5,y+5, x+5,y-5)
    end
    -- Draw lines between control points
    for i=1,#controlPoints do
        colour(0xff,0x00,0x00, 100)
        local cp1 = controlPoints[i]
        local cp2 = controlPoints[i+1]
        if cp1 and cp2 then
            line(cp1.x, cp1.y
                ,cp2.x, cp2.y)
        end
    end
end
```

If you'd like to play with it: [Get LÖVE](https://love2d.org/) and put the above code into `main.lua` in its own directory. Put [`vector.lua`](https://github.com/vrld/hump/blob/master/vector.lua) from the [`HUMP`](https://github.com/vrld/hump) library in the same directory. Run it as `love <that-directory>` from a command line.

Move the mouse around! The middle control point is set to the mouse location:

[image: Setting control point with mouse]

Comment: Anko have u tried LibGdx? if so, do u prefer Löve? I am moving away from using standard android API after my current game and Im trying to decide between LibGdx and Löve. Interesting answer above as always btw

Comment: @Anko Thanks a lot, it's more than i expected. More i think i can easly understand your code since i use MonkeyX for my game which is similar to LUA.

Comment: @iQ I haven't used Libgdx, but I've read lots about it and I know Java well. Libgdx is *big*. (It has accelerometer support, built in curve generators and everything), while Love2D is *very small* (it doesn't have any of those, theres' no shader support, etc). Thanks to its simplicity though, Love2D has been great for quick prototypes and small games, but it might be too minimalist for some projects. Who knows. (You do! [Try it](https://love2d.org/wiki/Getting_Started) and see. :D)

Comment: Great answer, and  that GIF is really a nice bonus!